# Closed form of a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, closed-form

Is there any closed form or a bound for a matrix product of this kind
$$ P=\prod_{i=1}^n \begin{pmatrix} 1-a & a \\ b_i & 1-b_i \end{pmatrix}, \quad a,b_i \in [0,1] $$ for an arbitrary sequence $\{b\}_i$? Essentially, I am trying to estimate a distribution of non-homogeneous Markov chain at time $n$, specifically, I would like to find the upper left corner of $P$:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} P \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$